# Audio organizing via CLI

Tags: linux, command-line, audio, libraries, id3

I'm looking for some software for my OpenSUSE, which with I would be able to organize my audio files.

I've found one, which may be good, but it's unable to run without X server (in CLI).
http://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Picard

**I'm not looking for ID3 renamers.** There're maybe hundreds of them... I'm looking for software, which has its own database, or is able to communicate with some database, like CDDB, Gracenote, last.fm etc.

Comment: so you're looking for a CLI library management tool, or a CLI interface to some library manager?

Comment: I'm looking for whatever, what can get ID3 tags from some database like CDDB, Gracenote or whatever... Because I don't have ID3 tags in my files...

Comment: And the software should be able to run in CLI - e.g.

MySoftware /var/myDirWithMusic/track1.mp3

will cause getting ID3 tags and write these tags into track1.mp3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not big fan of "organizers" - I do my own organization with folders, and alike, but check xmms2 (not xmms!).

xmms2 is a daemon, which tracks your collection, and is operated using some kind of client - for example standard nyxmms2 cli app.

Comment: yeah, that's kinda what i was thinking about.  i'm not very familiar with it tho; not sure if there are tag maintenance plugins for it.  (i'm with you on "let me organize my own files, tyvm" tho.) :)

Comment: Yeah, until now I've been doing my organization on my own, but what if I have 10 albums in one dir and each of the track has no ID3 tag and it's name is Track%201, Track%2050 etc.?
For me it's really anoying and I would rather use some organizer. I don't believe, that there's no that software, like Picard, for CLI.

Comment: One more note - if/when you have files organized in folders - I find that the best audio player is MOC ( http://moc.daper.net/ )

Answer (score 2):

nothign quite as polished, but you chould check out [beets](http://beets.radbox.org/) or [albumidentify](http://github.com/scottr/albumidentify) In this case its more music fingerprinting and metadata you're after, rather than organisation